# Probability on drawing colored balls,

Tags: probability

A bag contains five blue balls and three red balls. A boy draws a ball, and then draws another without replacement.  Suppose a third ball is drawn without replacement. Find:

(a) P(no red balls left after third draw).

(b) P(one red ball left).

(c) P(first red ball on last draw).

(d) P(a red ball on last draw).

I have the answers for all 4, but don't know how to get (c) $5/28$, (d)$3/8$.

I got:
(a): $\dfrac{3c3}{8c5}$

(b) $\dfrac{3c2 \cdot 5c1}{8c3}$

Comment: For $c$:  the only winning sequence is $BBR$, so $\frac 58\times \frac 47\times \frac 36$.  Note:  $d$ is much easier, just think about it.

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the probability that the first red ball is selected on the third draw?

As lulu observed in the comments, in order for this event to occur, a black ball must be selected on the first draw, another black ball must be selected on the second draw, then a red ball must be selected on the third draw.  Hence, 
$$\Pr(\text{first red on third draw}) = \Pr(B)\Pr(B \mid B)\Pr(R \mid B \cap B) = \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{5}{28}$$

> What is the probability that a red ball is selected on the third draw?

Imagine that all eight balls were being selected sequentially without replacement.  This creates a sequence of black and red balls.  A red ball is equally likely to be anywhere in this sequence.  The probability that a red ball is selected third is the probability that one of the three red balls is in the third position in the sequence.  Since there are a total of eight balls, this probability is $3/8$.